# comparing between two VM snapshots?

Tags: virtual-machine, malware, snapshot

I already know some programs can compare between two snapshots but they only work on my real machine but I want to know how to know the difference between two virtual machine snapshots

```
Example :

->Create new VirtualBox virtual machine 

->Install windows

-> take snapshot (1)

->Execute a malware

->take snapshot (2)
```

now how can i know the new , the edited and the deleted files or registry keys or any other thing *( What the malware have done on the system )* ???

> Please focus on how to know the file changes

Comment: Your step 4 is interesting: "Execute a malware" :)

Comment: Take a look: http://serverfault.com/questions/41683/are-there-any-tools-to-diff-two-vmware-windows-xp-images

Comment: it was a great idea but i'm already using the same program but there are two problems 1) it takes a long time 2) it can't detect what rootkits have done "they can hide their files & registry keys" , Thank you anyway ^_^

Comment: Ever come up with a solution to this?